# GAS/Javascript: How do I set values to only empty rows at the bottom of the sheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that runs every day and each day new values are set to google sheet. My worry is each time the scripts runs, it overwrites existing data. What I want is for the data set on the last row at the bottom of the sheet so that there is a continuation. I have tried with my code below but it's not working.  How do I do this?

```
 var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var lr=ss.getLastRow();
 var range = ss.getRange(1,10,lr-1)
 for (var j = 0; j < requestObjects.length; j++) {

  if(requestObjects[j].TimeOffTypeName != "Sick") {
        ss.getRange(1 + j,1).setValue(requestObjects[j].Firstname);
        ss.getRange(1+ j, 2).setValue(requestObjects[j].Lastname);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,3).setValue(requestObjects[j].LoginID);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,4).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffTypeName);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,5).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffDayOfWeek);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,6).setValue(requestObjects[j].SubmittedDate);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,7).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffHours);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,8).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffDate);
        ss.getRange(1 + j,11).setValue(requestObjects[j].Status);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (if objects values are ordered. If not, use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get values) to create a output array and then output that array:

```
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 const lr = ss.getLastRow();
 const output = requestObjects.map(obj => Object.values(obj));
 //const output = requestObjects.map(({Firstname,LastName,LoginID}) => [Firstname, LastName, LoginID]);//destructuring
 ss.getRange(lr + 1, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);//batch set values on the lr+1
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).